# If $f(-f\circ f\circ\ldots\circ f(0)) - f(f\circ \ldots\circ f(0))\cdot f(-f\circ\ldots\circ f(0))$ what is $f(0)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $$f(-\underbrace{f(f(\ldots f(0)\ldots))}_{\text{n times}})-f(\underbrace{f(f(\ldots f(0)\ldots))}_{\text{n-1 times}})\cdot f(-\underbrace{f(f(\ldots f(0)\ldots))}_{\text{n-1 times}}) = f(0), \quad\forall n \in \mathbb{N^*} $$
>   What can we say about $f(0)$?

I'm trying to solve a functional equation and I noticed that the above statement is true. I guess that it is $f(0)=0$, but is the above sufficient to prove it?

Comment: Try:  $f(n)=2$ for $n≥0$, $f(n)=-2$ for $n<0$.

Answer (score 1):

Try:   $$f(n) =
\begin{cases}
2,  & \text{if $n≥0$} \\[2ex]
-2, & \text{if $n<0$}
\end{cases}$$

More generally:  $$f(n) =
\begin{cases}
A,  & \text{if $n≥0$} \\[2ex]
\frac A{1-A}, & \text{if $n<0$}
\end{cases}$$

For $A>1$.

Of course, you can invalidate these examples if you require that $f$ be continuous, at least at $x=0$.